# pjax fragment troubles

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, pjax

I'm trying to use pjax's fragment option to refresh only a part of a page. Nothing happens on click and there are no errors thrown, only a hard page reload. No ajax call is being made. Testing in chrome

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>PJAX TEST</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="/css/index-style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
          <ul id="navlist">
            <li><a href="/index.html">click</a></li>
            <li><a href="/one/index.html">click 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/two/index.html">click 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/three/index.html">click 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="container">

          <div id="inner-content">

            <h1>YEA YEA - INDEX PAGE</h1>
            <div id="text-block">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            <h3>Sticky footer</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

and the script.js is

```
$(function(){


    $('li a').pjax("#container", { fragment: "#container" });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had to add

```
<div id="container" data-pjax-container>
```

to the container and

```
$(document).pjax('a', '[data-pjax-container]', { fragment: "#container" });
```

to JS